# What is the alternative to ClientResponse in Resteasy 3 and above?

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy

I am currently working with Resteasy 2.3.6.Final and want to upgrade to Resteasy 3.0.4.Final.  However, the [API doc](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/javadocs/org/jboss/resteasy/client/ClientResponse.html) indicates that the class is now deprecated.  So my questions are:

1. What is the reason that ClientResponse is deprecated?  Is this to do with the fact that JAX-RS 2.0 was introduced in Resteasy 3+?
2. What is the recommended return type of Resteasy resources now?  I read the [user doc](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.4.Final/userguide/html/RESTEasy_Client_Framework.html), and in section 47.2 there are some examples.  It suggested using javax.ws.rs.core.Response if you want to get everything back, but this will remove the generic parameter.  How do I keep the generic parameter?

Thanks for any help.

**Edit 1**

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

I currently some code like this:

```
   @GET
   @Path("matrixParam")
   @Produces("application/json")
   ClientResponse<Matrix> getMatrix(@MatrixParam("param")String param);
```

ClientResponse takes in a generic parameter.  If I use Response instead, then it would become:

```
   @GET
   @Path("matrixParam")
   @Produces("application/json")
   Response getMatrix(@MatrixParam("param")String param);
```

And the generic parameter is removed.  This would be inconvenient because the caller needs to know what type the returned object is.

**Edit 2**

The [answer from Pascal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20616337/842860) and the book `Restful Java with JAX-RS 2.0` both say that the generic parameter is no longer needed because the interface methods can return the desired type directly.  Thanks Pascal for answering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the generic parameter anymore as you can directly use your own type in the client interface method like this:

```
    @GET
    @Path("matrixParam")
    @Produces("application/json")
    Matrix getMatrix(@MatrixParam("param")String param);
```

And to query the remote service you can use the resteasy client proxy framework:

```
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://host/path");
    ResteasyWebTarget rsWebTarget = (ResteasyWebTarget)target;
    SimpleMatrixClient simple = rsWebTarget.proxy(SimpleMatrixClient.class);
    Matrix m = simple.getMatrix("myMatrixParamValue");
```

Comment: what if the response is sometimes empty? e.g. 204 i dont get a response entity...but itll be difficult for me to check e.g. the response status if i returned directly the entity.